# How do you give each instance of a component its own props that change independently?

Tags: reactjs

The way it's currently setup, when a `cell` component is clicked, the background color of every cell changes to red or black, as opposed to only that cell. How can I make it so that each `cell` component's `currentColor` prop is unique to it and changes independently?

Relevant bits from **`App.js`**:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      grid: [
        [{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],
        [{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],
        [{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],
        [{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],
        [{},{},{},{},{},{},{}],
     ],
      currentColor: "red",
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log('The circle was clicked and will change to this color: ' + this.state.currentColor);
    if (this.state.currentColor === "red"){
      this.setState(state => ({
        currentColor: "black"
      }));
    }
    else{
      this.setState(state => ({
        currentColor: "red"
      }));
    }
  }


  render(){
    console.log("Grid length is: " + this.state.grid.length)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <GridContainer grid={this.state.grid} currentColor={this.state.currentColor} handleClick={this.handleClick}/>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

These props are then passed down in this manner: App -> GridContainer -> RowContainer -> Cell

Child component **`Cell.js`**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledCell = styled.div`
  background-color: ${props => props.currentColor};
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 1rem;
  width: 133px;
  height: 100px;
`;


class Cell extends Component {

  render() {
    return(
        <StyledCell onClick={this.props.handleClick} currentColor = {this.props.currentColor}>
        </StyledCell>
      )
  }

}

export default Cell;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're changing the color once at the top level, the same value is being passed down to all of the children components.  If you want to have a color that is specific to each component instance, you can either give internal state to the Cell component to govern its own color, or store each cell's color independently in your grid object, then map over the array and pass each color as props and adjust the handler to [lift up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) the state changes from the Cell.  I'd give an example but it's almost 5. Cheers.

**Update:**

I think the 2nd approach is probably better, in which case you'd turn your App's grid state into something like:

```
this.state.grid = [
[{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" }],
[{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" }],
[{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" }],
[{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" }],
[{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" },{ color: "red" }]
]
```

and replace your click handler with one that sets the color for the specific Cell you're targeting:

```
function colorCell(row, col, color) {
  let grid = Array.from(this.state.grid);
  grid[row][col].color = color;
  this.setState({ grid: grid })
}
```

Pass that function all the way down as props to your Cells like you're doing, along with their respective row/column indexes, and call it in a click handler attached to the cell.

That's the gist anyway.